# How to pipe the tidy-ed lm model CI's into ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following code that is computing for every year bewteen `1961:2018` the effects of both predictor variables: base on balls per game (BB) and home runs per game (HR) on the response variable runs per game (R):

```
rm(list = ls())

library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(Lahman)

fit <- Teams %>% 
  filter(yearID %in% 1961:2018) %>% 
  mutate(BB = BB / G, 
         HR = HR / G,
         R = R / G) %>%
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(R ~ BB + HR, data = .), conf.int = TRUE)) %>% filter(term=="BB")
fit

> fit
# A tibble: 58 x 8
# Groups:   yearID [58]
   yearID term  estimate std.error statistic p.value conf.low conf.high
    <int> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1   1961 BB      0.0845     0.168     0.502   0.623  -0.274      0.443
 2   1962 BB      0.142      0.273     0.520   0.610  -0.434      0.718
 3   1963 BB      0.339      0.242     1.40    0.178  -0.171      0.849
 4   1964 BB     -0.105      0.302    -0.349   0.731  -0.742      0.532
 5   1965 BB      0.235      0.253     0.928   0.366  -0.299      0.768
 6   1966 BB      0.104      0.216     0.482   0.636  -0.351      0.559
 7   1967 BB      0.0660     0.223     0.296   0.771  -0.405      0.537
 8   1968 BB     -0.199      0.203    -0.983   0.340  -0.627      0.229
 9   1969 BB      0.153      0.163     0.942   0.357  -0.185      0.492
10   1970 BB      0.239      0.157     1.52    0.143  -0.0874     0.566
# ... with 48 more rows
```

I now would like to output this "fit" which is actually a tibble (or modernized data frame) into ggplot to show the estimates per year as points but also the regression line along with the CI's computed by the `lm` model and not simply recomputing it with `geom_smooth(method = "lm")`.

I have tried the following without success. I know that the `augment` from broom should operate on the `lm` model output directly and therefore the following code is wrong but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
augment(fit) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(yearID, estimate)) +
  geom_line(aes(yearID, .fitted), col = "blue")
```

How can I do that without "cheating" (double computing the `lm` once and then on the ggplot as well) and doing:

```
fit %>% ggplot(aes(yearID,estimate)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `predict(fit,...)` and plotting that?

Comment: You are wanting to plot a linear fit on an independent variable of a previous linear fit - not sure why, but that fit does not exist in the "fit" object.  you will have to compute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a similar route to Patrick, using `map()` and `nest()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(Lahman)
library(magrittr)

fit <- Teams %>%
  filter(yearID %in% 1961:2018) %>%
  mutate(
    BB = BB / G,
    HR = HR / G,
    R  = R / G
  ) %>%
  nest(data = -yearID) %>%
  mutate(
    model  = map(data, ~ lm(R ~ BB + HR, .x)),  # apply model to all nested groups
    m_tidy = map(model, tidy),                  # tidy up
    est    = map_dbl(m_tidy, ~ .x %>%           # pull BB estimate from each group
      filter(term == "BB") %>%
      pull(estimate)),
  )
```

Now at this point you could just `%$%` right into this next portion but I've kept them separate here so talk about mimicking the confidence interval properly. The `geom_smooth()` confidence interval is based on the t-distribution and not the normal distribution. Thus, we'll have to do a bit of extra work to get out intervals to work:

```
fit %$%
  lm(est ~ yearID) %>%
  augment() %>% 
  mutate(m.se.fit = .se.fit * qt(1 - (1-0.95)/2, nrow(fit))) %>% # 95% conf int calc
  ggplot(aes(yearID, est)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted), col = "blue") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .fitted - m.se.fit, ymax = .fitted + m.se.fit), alpha = .2)
```

[image]

This plot essentially mirrors the desired plot:

```r
fit %>% ggplot(aes(yearID, est)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map` functions from the purrr package, which is included in tidyverse. A possible code for your described problem is listed below. Should also be possible with `lapply` if you are not that familar with the purrr package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(Lahman)

fit <- Teams %>% 
  filter(yearID %in% 1961:2018) %>% 
  mutate(BB = BB / G, 
         HR = HR / G,
         R = R / G) %>%
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  # consolidate your data
  nest() %>% 
  # creates new nested column with your regression data
  mutate(model = map(data, function(df) 
    tidy(lm(R ~ BB + HR, data = df), conf.int = TRUE) %>%
      filter(term=="BB")
    ),
    # extract the column estimate
    model_est = map_dbl(model, function(df) 
      df %>% pull(estimate)
    ), 
    # extract the column conf.low
    model_conf.low = map_dbl(model, function(df) 
      df %>% pull(conf.low)
    ), 
    # extract the column conf.high
    model_conf.high = map_dbl(model, function(df) 
      df %>% pull(conf.high)
    )
   ) 


fit %>% ggplot(aes(yearID,model_est)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(yearID, model_conf.low)) + 
  geom_line(aes(yearID, model_conf.high))
```